# Convert C# Hash Code to PHP for REST API Connection

Tags: c#, php, rest

Below is an excerpt from documentation for connecting to an API.  I need to make this connection with PHP, but I am coming up short.  Examples of what the public and private keys look like are:

- **Public Key:** 9cd52302-85cf-406d-98df-d3e19eea907c
- **Private Key:** 7cd0e56a-a62f-4f05-ab8c-e1a2255c9732

The documentation with a C# example is below.  From what I have read, my issue appears to be a difference between the hashing operations in C# and PHP, but I can't seem to get the right combination going.  Every attempt I make results in a response from the API of 'Invalid Username or Password'.  My keys being returned from hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $privateKey) are lowercase and look nothing like the example.  I understand the UTF8 and Base64 encoding requirements, but the hashing is getting me.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Excerpt below:

**Authorization Token**

The authorization token consists of {Rep Public Key}:{Request Signature} (color coded for emphasis). The public key identifies the user making the request. The request signature is a secure, system-generated string similar to a password, consisting of several pieces of information about the request and encrypted using HMAC SHA-256 and the rep's private key. Upon receiving the request, the API attempts to match the signature.

**Create an Authorization Token**

Follow these steps to encrypt the request signature and rep public key:

1. Apply UTF8 encoding to the rep private key and request signature, i.e. {HTTP Method}|{URI}|{Time Stamp}.
2. Convert the signature string to lower case.
3. Encrypt the signature string using HMAC SHA-256 and the rep's private key.

   - **Example:** get|/api/accounts/1052932|thu, 18 jun 2015 07:25:43 gmt
   - **Becomes:** RVg3YCtybLImF68rEumuPLCCApLnPIyNvb0hfxH+ek4=
4. Apply Base64 encoding to the {Rep Public Key}:{Encrypted Request Signature} string.

   - **Example:** 3383259B-9FBA-486E-97A8-E81893741F83:RVg3YCtybLImF68rEumuPLCCApLnPIyNvb 0hfxH+ek4=
   - **Becomes:** MzM4MzI1OUItOUZCQS00ODZFLTk3QTgtRTgxODkzNzQxRjgzOlJWZzNZQ3R5YkxJbU Y2OHJFdW11UExDQ0FwTG5QSXlOdmIwaGZ4SCtlazQ9

**Encryption Code in .NET C#**

```
var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
var keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
var messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
{
    var hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
}
```

Comment: Do you think its a good idea to be publishing a **Private Key** here??

Comment: @RiggsFolly read again mate.. "_Examples of what the public and private keys look like_"

Comment: @dehood Phew, thats a relief

Comment: @RiggsFolly i know right

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I think posting valid private keys would be a terrible idea.  ;)  I generated those as an example for the purpose of giving the most complete information possible.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  Step three should have a second step.  You have to Base64 encode the signature string, too.